# Largest file in the system and move it in unix

Tags: bash, unix

I am new to bash and im struggling with it. I have an assignment which the question is

Try to find that top 5 larger files in the entire file system ordered by size and move the file to /tmp folder and rename the file with current datetime format

I tried with the following code

```
du -a /sample/ | sort -n -r | head -n 5
```

Im getting the list, but i cannot able to move..

Suggestions please

Comment: [xargs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html)

Comment: could you please explain

Comment: Are you sure you want the largest files in the entire file system? Or is the question of getting the largest file system?

Comment: Largest file in the system

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a simple case of [xargs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html):

```
du -a /sample/ | sort -n -r | head -n 5 | xargs -I{} mv {} /tmp
```

`xargs` here simply reads lines from standard input and appends them as arguments to the command, `mv` in this case. Because the `-I{}` is specified, the `{}` string is replaced for the argument by `xargs`. So `mv {} /tmp` is executed as `mv <the first file> /tmp` and `mv <the second file> /tmp` and so on. You can ex. add `-t` option to `xargs` or ex. add `echo` to see what's happenning: `xargs -I{} -t echo mv {} /tmp`.

Instead of running 5 processes, we could add /tmp on the end of the stream and run only one `mv` command:

```
{ du -a /sample/ | sort -n -r | head -n 5; echo /tmp; } | xargs mv
```

or like:

```
du -a . | sort -n -r | head -n 5 | { tee; echo /tmp; } | xargs mv
```

Note that using `du -a` will most probably not work with filenames with special characters, spaces, tabs and newlines. It will also include directories in it's output. If you want to filter the files only, move to much safer `find`:

```
find /sample/ -type f -printf '%s\t%p\n' | sort -n -r | cut -f2- | head -n5 | xargs -I{} mv {} /tmp
```

First we print each filename with it's size in bytes. Then we numerically sort the stream. Then we remove the size, ie. cut the stream on first `'\t'` tabulation. Then we get the `head -n5` lines. Lastly, we copy with `xargs`. It will work for filenames not having special characters in filenames, like unreadable bytes, spaces, newlines and tabs.

For such corner cases it's preferred to use `find` and handle zero terminated strings, like this (note simply just `-z` and `-0` options added):

```
find /sample/ -type f -printf '%s\t%p\0' | sort -z -n -r | cut -z -f2- | head -z -n5 | xargs -0 -I{} mv {} /tmp
```

Comment: Why not `-print0` instead of `-printf '%s\t%p\0'`?

Comment: mv: cannot stat ‘0’: No such file or directory
mv: inter-device move failed: ‘/home/devops2/sample/’ to ‘/tmp/sample’; unable to remove target: Directory not empty

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I need to sort by size, so I need to print the size of the file with the filename, sort it by file size and then extract the filename only.

Comment: @Madan The `du` output includes folders too, so if you du `du -a /sample/` it will include the directory `/sample/` size too. If you have only files in your directory, you could glob it `du -a /sample/*`. Well, we could filter files with something like `xargs -i sh -c '[ -f "$1" ] && printf "%s\n" "$1"' --`, but such would slow it down. Just use `find`, `find -type f`, and always use `find` in scripts.

Comment: Im struggling with difficulties.. Its like everything out of sequences..

Comment: cannot stat ‘4\t/home/devops2/sample/N’: No such file or directory
4/t is added, the size is added